# distance between current location and updated location

Tags: swift, location, cllocationmanager

i want to get the distance between two location.

first location is my current location and the other location is the user updated location.

so, how to track user location and measure the distance between the current location and user updated location

i tried this code and the measure is not true.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let loc = locations.last else {return}

    guard let startLocation = startLocation else {
        self.startLocation = loc
        return
    }
    guard let current = manager.location else { return }

    let distance = current.distance(from: startLocation)
    print("Distance: \((distance))")
}
```

Comment: You should get the distance in meters, what output you get ?

Comment: i already get distance in meter but the result is not logic to me as i get distace although mobile does not change from its position

Comment: Check the accuracy, you can change it to be more accurate.
CLLocation has the horizontal and vertical accuracy, [check here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation#1669564)